# How do plasma radiative losses scale with temperature in the range 5kev to 1MeV (holding density constant)?

Tags: thermal-radiation

The $T^4$ blackbody radiation rule breaks down well below 1MeV because of new effects like bremstrahlung, inverse compton scattering, etc. It would be great to have a chart of temperature vs aggregate radiative losses in watts per nanogram for deuterium at a density of $10^{14}$ particles per $m^3$ for temperatures up to 1MeV. But I'd settle for a rough estimate of the exponent on the power law (the n in $E = k T^n$) in that temperature range.